# How to hide text if query has no posts?

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide the text with the word reviews if query has no posts. Please ask for suggestions.

is image > [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beVb3.jpg)

```
        <h1 class="section-title"><span>Reviews</span></h1>
            <?php
                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'movies', 'string');
                $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

                $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'cat'         => '21',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'movies',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $term_ids,
                            'operator'=> 'IN' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
                        )),
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
                ) );

                //Loop through posts and display...
                    if($second_query->have_posts()) {

                        while ($second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); 
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'list-01' );
                        ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of jQuery, just put the `h1` tag after the `If statement` and before `while`. Then if your query is not empty it will display the title otherwise not

**Like this:**

```
                <?php
                $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'movies', 'string');
                $term_ids = wp_list_pluck($terms,'term_id');

                $second_query = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'cat'         => '21',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'movies',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $term_ids,
                            'operator'=> 'IN' //Or 'AND' or 'NOT IN'
                        )),
                    'posts_per_page' => 6,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'post__not_in'=>array($post->ID)
                ) );

                //Loop through posts and display...
                    if($second_query->have_posts()) { ?>
                    <h1 class="section-title"><span>Reviews</span></h1>
                     <?php while ($second_query->have_posts() ) : $second_query->the_post(); 
                        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'list-01' );
                        ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); }?>
```

Comment: I am confused that on the h1 line to Error.

Comment: True I forgot to close and open the php tags again, I updated the code